# Scaffolding an existing SQLite database with EF core results in a generic context and no entities for the tables

Tags: c#, sqlite, entity-framework-core

The command I'm inputting into pmc is
`Scaffold-DbContext "DataSource=C:\SQLite\Databases\Ticket0.db3" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite -OutputDir C:\WPFTutorials\TicketEF\TicketEF\DB -context TicketContext -force`
I've checked and double checked the data source, but it only generates a generic context and no tables (I can't include images as I don't have high enough reputation).

I also checked on stack overflow but the closest relevant post I could find was this [SQLite scaffolding with Entity Framework Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37984456/sqlite-scaffolding-with-entity-framework-core), however the problem there was relative pathing whereas I am using an absolute path.
Another I tried was [Scaffold (reverse engineering) existing database return empty sets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59726563/scaffold-reverse-engineering-existing-database-return-empty-sets) and tried commenting out the `<Nullable>enable</Nullable>` which solved their issue but that didn't work either.

I have the

`Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore, Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design, Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite and Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools`

NuGet packages installed.

In case it matters the database I am trying to connect can be opened and changed in SQLiteStudio so it should be working fine, and it has 5 tables and 2 views.

Comment: What means "and no tables"? An empty "OnModelCreating"?

Comment: Maybe the file is empty?

Comment: Are there any tables in that database? Trying random answers, especially for deprecated library versions, won't fix *your* problem

Comment: `I can't include images` *don't* use images. Images can't be googled, copied, compiled or tested. Post the database schema and generated code as *text* in the question itself

Comment: @Klamsi yes the OnModelCreating is empty.

Comment: What if you explicitly specify a table name (with --table myTableName)?

Comment: I figured it out thanks to @GuruStron, I had been using the wrong filename and mistook the generated file for the original. Thank you for the suggestions. Should I delete this question since it was my own minor mistake?

Comment: Welcome to SO, Shane. If it is only a typo that you figure out, and the whole question is meaningless, it is better to delete it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What had happened was that I mistyped the database location as "Ticket0" which is how it appeared in SQLiteStudio and EF Core generated an empty Ticket0.db3 which I'd then mistaken for the original file.

Since it's my own mistake should I delete the question?

Answer (score 0):

I have modified your code to the below and it's working.

Scaffold-DbContext -provider Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite "DataSource=C:\SQLite\Databases\Ticket0.db3" -OutputDir C:\WPFTutorials\TicketEF\TicketEF\DB -context TicketContext -force

Comment: Welcome to SO! Try to use the code tag {} for code (CTRL-K), like `session.findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey(0)`.